# Error when running a typescript react app with docker compose

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I want to run a typescript monorepo with a nodejs backend and a create-react-app frontend.
First i am trying to get the frontend running in a container. The application runs locally fine.

I want to change code in the host machine and have the code in the container update automatically.

When I run `docker-compose up -d` I see the error below.

```
> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /app/src
```

folder structure

```
repo
 - backend
 - frontend
   - Dockerfile
   - build
   - public
   - src
     - index.tsx
 - docker-compose.yaml
```

DockerFile

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
   frontend:
      builds: ./frontend
      ports:
       - '3000:3000'
      volumes:
       - './frontend/src:/app/src'
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
volumes:
   data:
   logs:
```

###### edit1: docker-compose.yaml after trying suggested solution

```
version: "3.8"
services:
   frontend:
      builds: ./frontend
      ports:
       - '3000:3000'
      volumes:
       - './frontend:/app'
       - /app/node_modules
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
```

error after running `docker-compose up -d` the container logs show

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app/package.json'
```

note:  Strangely, removing the workdir in the Dockerfile runs the container but installs everything in the top level and not in the /app directory. When I remove volumes entirely the container runs fine as well (still a deal breaker).

###### edit2: I feel the issue has something to do with the project folder structure and paths. If i place the docker-compose file in the `frontend` directory the container serves the react app and local code changes auto update in the container.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `tsconfig.json` file is in `frontend`, it won't be present in your container so you'll be missing crucial parts like

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "jsx": "react-jsx"
}
```

A more typical approach is to volume mount the entire application directory and create an anonymous volume mount so as to not clobber `node_modules`

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/app
  - /app/node_modules # anonymous volume mount
```

Comment: adding these lines causes a new error `can't find app/package.json`. removing the volumes section entirely allows me to run the container just without local changes being sent to the container which is a deal breaker.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show what you changed? Please also include the new error message in full and where you see it